# Searching List with Dictionary, Conditional Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, search

I have a list, `categories`, which stores some different values. I'm using a dictionary, `my_dict` to see if there are specific values within `categories` that match. If there are, a unique function would be performed for each key in the dictionary.

My code currently looks like:

```
categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']

my_dict = {
    'Conditioners': lambda: print(1),
    'Bath': lambda: print(2),
    'Shaving Gels': lambda: print(3)
}


for category in categories:
    fn = my_dict.get(category, lambda: None)
    fn()
```

Which outputs:

```
 2
```

What I would like to now do is, if in any case, I had 2 or more values in the dictionary which were in `categories` I would like to do a unique function, different than the ones specified for them individually.

For example:

```
categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Personal Care']

my_dict = {
    'Creams': lambda: print(1),
    'Bath': lambda: print(2),
    'Shaving Gels': lambda: print(3)
}


for category in categories:
    fn = my_dict.get(category, lambda: None)
    fn()
```

Instead of it printing `1` and `2`, I would like to do perform a different function, for example, `print('ABC')`.

Any direction on how I might achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you expand on this:
"I would like to do a unique function, different than the ones specified for them individually."

Can you change the lambdas in the `dict` to be whatever functions you want?

Comment: I can change the lambdas in the dictionary to be whatever I need them to be. Essentially, I'm just looking for a different lambda if two or more key values match the contents of the list.

Comment: Okay, I'll change up my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper to check if this condition is met, then run whatever you want if it is. Since you can't execute the functions until after you know only one category matches, you need to go through categories twice.

```
def two_or_more_categories_in_dict(categories, dict):
    """Returns true if there are more than two categories in the dict"""
    num_cats_in_dict = 0
    for cat in categories:
        if cat in dict:
            num_cats_in_dict += 1
    if num_cats_in_dict > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


    categories = ['Creams', 'Bath', 'Shaving Gels']    

    my_dict = {
        'Creams': f1,
        'Bath': f2,
        'Shaving Gels': f3
    }

    if two_or_more_categories_in_dict(categories, dict):
        #<unique lambda for this case>
    else:
        for category in categories:
            fn = my_dict.get(category, lambda: None)
            fn()
```